General degree distribution of Soft Random geometric Graphs
I am interested in the degree distributions of Soft Random Geometric Graphs, and was wondering if anyone could give me some input. Soft RGG's are random graphs, which are constructed by first distributing $n$ nodes uniformly at random in some metric space $(M,d)$, and then connecting every pair of nodes $x,y$ with probability $f(d(x,y))$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ is called a connection function.
Here are my thoughts. If you can calculate the probability that two randomly chosen points in $M$ connect subject to a connection function, lets call this probability $c_f$, then won't we just have a $G(n,c_f)$ graph, and thus a $Bin(n,c_f)$ degree distribution? I worked out an example where $M = [0,1], f(x) = 1-x$, and $d$ the euclidean distance. We would then see that
\begin{align*}
        c_f &= \int_0^1\int_0^1f(d(x,y))dxdy,\\
        &= \int_0^1\int_0^1(1-|x-y|)dxdy,\\
        &=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^x(1-x+y)dy+\int_x^1(1-y+x)dy\right)dx,\\
        &=\int_0^1(x-x^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2 + 1-\frac{1}{2} +x -x +\frac{1}{2}x^2-x^2)dx,\\
        &=\int_0^1(\frac{1}{2} +x-x^2)dx,\\
        &=\frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}
I coded this problem up, and numerically it seems to check out. Does my thought process seem correct? If it is, I doubt I am the first to put it on paper, so I would greatly appreciate other relevant sources. Thanks in advance!

There's two places where we don't have the necessary independence to make the claims in the question.
Problems with the degree distribution
First of all, the degree distribution is not exactly binomial. It is approximately binomial in RGGs with a small cutoff, and so it should also be approximately binomial in soft RGGs where the connection function drops off sufficiently quickly. In general, though, the problem is that a centrally placed vertex has a higher degree on average than a vertex near the boundary of our metric space (if there is a boundary).
In the example with $M = [0,1]$ with the Euclidean metric and $f(x) = 1-x$, we get:

The connection probability for a vertex at $x=\frac12$ is $\int_{y=0}^1 (1 - |y-\frac12|)\,\mathrm dy = \frac34$.
But a vertex at $x=0$ has connection probability $\int_{y=0}^1 (1-y)\,\mathrm dy = \frac12$.
In general, a vertex at a point $x$ has connection probability $\int_{y=0}^1 (1 - |y-x|)\,\mathrm dx = \frac12 + x - x^2$.

The average value of $\frac12 + x - x^2$ is $\frac23$, but that doesn't mean that the degree distribution of a vertex is $\text{Binomial}(n-1, \frac23)$: rather, the degree distribution is the margin of a joint distribution $\text{Binomial}(n-1, \frac12 + x - x^2)$ where $x$ is uniformly chosen from $[0,1]$.
For a concrete difference between the two, suppose that $n=10$, so there are $9$ other vertices. Then a $\text{Binomial}(n-1,\frac23)$ has a $(\frac23)^9 \approx 0.026$ chance of being equal to $9$, but the actual probability that a vertex is adjacent to all $9$ others is $$\int_{x=0}^1 \left(\frac12 + x - x^2\right)^9 \,\mathrm dx \approx 0.037.$$
This problem goes away if our metric space is symmetric enough: for example, if $M = S^1$ with the arc length metric, then the degree distribution really is $\text{Binomial}(n-1,c_f)$, because every vertex location is equivalent.
Also, if we keep $M = [0,1]$, but instead of $f(x) = 1-x$, we take something like $f(x) = \max\{0, 1 - 100x\}$, then all vertex locations in $[0.01, 0.99]$ have the same connection probability (of $1/5000$, I think), so $\text{Binomial}(n-1,1/5000)$ is very nearly the degree distribution; this will happen whenever $f(x)$ is $0$ or very small for large $x$.
Problems with independence of vertices
This might be less relevant to you if you just care about the degree distributions. However, even in cases where the degree distribution is $\text{Binomial}(n-1,c_f)$ or close to it, RGGs and soft RGGs will not be the same as $G(n,c_f)$, because edges are not independent.
In RGGs, this is easiest to see. Begin by choosing the locations of two vertices $x,y$. If they are adjacent, then they are close to each other, so probably they will get many common neighbors. If they are not adjacent, then most of the time, they are too far away to get any common neighbors.
Soft RGGs will relax this a little - even non-adjacent vertices have some chance of having a common neighbor no matter where they are, provided $f(x)$ is always positive. However, if $f(x)$ is decreasing, then it's still true that adjacent vertices have more common neighbors than non-adjacent vertices. One concrete effect of this is that we get many more large cliques.

Wow! Thank you for such a clear and well thought out answer, I really appreciate it. I do have some trouble following what you mean by  "the degree distribution is the margin of a joint distribution $Binomial(n−1,1/2+x−x^2 )$
where x
is uniformly chosen from [0,1]"
. Do you by any chance have any papers/books you recommend that give a more in depth introduction to (Soft) RGG's?

I mean that the pair (degree, point location) has a joint distribution where, conditioned on the point being at $x$, the degree distribution is $\text{Binomial}(n-1,\frac12+x-x^2)$. I don't have any textbook recommendations, unfortunately; I'd recommend Frieze and Karonski's Introduction to Random Graphs broadly speaking, but it has only a short section on RGGs and nothing on soft RGGs.
